# How can I prove that $2a^2 + 2b^2 > ab$

Tags: proof-writing

I know that this statement is true, but I cannot figure out a way to actually prove it. $a$ and $b$ are both positive real numbers.

Comment: You can start from $a^2+b^2-2ab=(a-b)^2>0$

Comment: I got it I just needed to think about it a little more, thanks!

Comment: @J.G.: the question says $a$ and $b$ are **positive** real numbers.

Comment: The proof is far easier than any of the algebraic manipulations would suggest. If $a = b$ this is obvious, and if $a > b$, then $ab < a\cdot a < 2a^2 < 2a^2 + 2b^2$. Likewise if $b > a$.

Answer (score 2):

$2a^2 + 2b^2 > ab \iff 4a^2 + 4b^2 > 2ab \iff 3a^2 + 3b^2 + (a-b)^2 > 0$ for $a,b$ positive.

Answer (score 1):

Dividing both sides by $ab$ gives
$$2\Big( \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a}\Big) > 1$$
Considering $\mu\equiv\frac{a}{b}$ and cleaning up a bit gives,
$$\mu +\mu^{-1} >\frac{1}{2}$$
$a$ and $b$ were positive reals, so $\mu:(0, 1]\cup[1,+\inf)$. Thus, the sum of $\mu$ and it's inverse must be great than one. $\square$

Comment: +1 for the funny proof...

Comment: @Isham Funny haha or funny strange? I'm sorry :(

Comment: funny  like somthing you don't expect...original I mean

Comment: @Isham Oh, thanks! I've got some wires in the wrong sockets

Answer (score 0):

Since $(a-b)^2>0$ for every real $a,b$ not both zero, we have that $$a^2+b^2>2ab>ab/2,$$ as wanted.